# Deleting a directory created with the wrong ownership

Tags: php

My script creates a directory. Before I realized that I needed to `chown()` the directory from apache to my user name so that I could access the uploaded files, I ran the script a few times.  Now I can't seem to get rid of the directory so I can start clean.

I figured that all I needed to do was write a PHP script to do is since within the script I would 'be' apache.  I've tried `rmdir` and `chown` but I keep getting `permission denied`.  I even tried loading the file in browser instead of just `php file.php` at the command line in case that affects the effective user.

What else can I try?

---

I already realized invoking the script from the command line would run it with my username as the user instead of the username that the web server runs it as (`apache`) so I've been invoking the script through the browser.  I've been simply trying to chown it to my user name so that I can delete it from the command line instead of trying to write some recursive `rmdir` function.

```
<?php
   $target = "/some/absolute/file/path";
   chown($target, "myself");
?>
```

Comment: When you run `php file.php` from your shell, you're running the php interpreter as yourself; the apache user is not doing anything and the apache software is not involved at all. You have to access the script through a web browser if you want apache to be the one executing it.

Comment: The file resides on the university server so I don't have any administrative rights.  If all else fails I can ask the server admin to delete it for me but since they're off for the holidays I wanted to try and fix this myself so I could finish the script.

Comment: @DanGrossman: Yes, I realized that already.  Unlike the command line I don't see any error output but the "page" loads and the file attributes don't change.

Comment: You could try to just chmod the directory from the php script to permissions you can delete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common problem on shared hosting, anyways there are several ways to fix that.

- PHP scripts are executed as "`www-user`" *only* when executed through the web server. If you run them from shell as `php script.php`, they are executed as the user you are logged in with -- let's call it "`shell-user`".
- Usually, an unprivileged user cannot change ownership of a file/directory.
- Instead, if your `www-user` and `shell-user` have a group in common (it depends on your shared hosting provider policies), you can just `chgrp` all the files/directories (recursively) to that group, change permissions on `440` for files, `770` for directories, and you will be able to manipulate them as `shell-user` too. Better way would be to use Posix ACLs to automatically set group/permissions, but it's not common to find that enabled on shared hostings.
- If you are lucky, and your shared hosting is good enough, you might be able to `sudo` to `www-user`, so that you can run commands as that user too. If not, the only way is making it run php scripts through the webserver.

### If you just want to delete directory recursively..

..you can use a function like this (From: https://gist.github.com/1407308):

```
/**
 * Delete a file or directory recursively.
 * @param string $path
 */
function rmtree($path) {
    if (is_dir($path)) {
        foreach (scandir($path) as $name) {
            if (in_array($name, array('.', '..'))) {
                continue;
            }
            $subpath = $path.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$name;
            rmtree($subpath);
        }
        rmdir($path);
    }
    else {
        unlink($path);
    }
}
```

Just beware that you *cannot* change ownership on dirs/files from an unprivileged user, only group and permissions.

Comment: Based on your last comment I changed my chown to a chmod and then deleted it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It may be that the permissions on that directory are read-only, or the directory may have files inside of it.

On the command line, try:

```
ls -l directory
```

That'll give you the permissions and ownership of the directory.  If it has 'w' set for the owner and the owner is apache, you should be able to use rmdir() in a script being run by the apache user unless there are contents.  So chdir into the directory and see if there are files - any files within the directory need to be removed first.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If executing the file from a browser gives you permissions other than the same username you use to login then your university has a serious security hole.

To check that you can do this:

```
<?php echo `whoami`; ?>
```

Also please post (at least a snippet of ) `ls -l` so we know what usernames are in use

Comment: It is standard for shared hosting to use a different user for shell and web server. Big problem is when you have to kill CGI scripts etc. In any case, a part from very very bad configurations, the webserver user is *not* the same for all users!